# Parse Json without property names to C#

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I'm trying to parse to a C# object a string containing a JSON that looks like that :
**I know it's not really valid json but I can't choose it, it's sent by a device.** That's why I've tried to replace the [] by {} to make it look like a valid object.

```
[2, "2", "text", {Object}]
```

I've created the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty(Order = 0)]
    public int TypeRequest { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 1)]
    public string UniqueID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 2)]
    public string Action { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Order = 3)]
    public JObject Payload { get; set; }

}
```

I want to parse the {Object} later (I need to know the "Action" property first because the object depends on the action).

So far I've done :

```
string userMessage = "[2, "2", "text", {Object}]"; 
if (userMessage.Length > 2)
{
     // We need to remove the first [ and the last ] to be able to parse into a json object
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(userMessage);
     sb[0] = '{';
     sb[sb.Length - 1] = '}';
     userMessage = sb.ToString();
 }

 JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 MyClass objectJSON = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass >(userMessage);
```

But it doesn't work I get the following exception:

> Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (3): {Object}}

I've also tried with JObject.Parse instead and I got:

> Invalid JavaScript property identifier character: ,. Path '', line 1,
>   position 2.

Do you know how to do it? I would like to avoid having to split my JSON by commas and have the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: Your userMessage should be wrapped in curly brackets `{}` not square brackets `[]` as that would indicate it's an array. It would then also need property names.

Comment: Try to validate your JSOn with: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: if there is a way to change input data into valid JSON - it will be the best option, otherwise custom parser to get {object} is needed.

Comment: Should be something like: {
 "TypeRequest": 2,
 "UniqueID": "2",
 "Action": "text",
 "Payload": {}
}

Comment: I don't choose the message it's sent by a device, I should have precised it sorry.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really a valid JSON because of `{Object}` so I removed it. You can technically do `json.Replace("{Object}", "something else")` to make it easier. Because you deal with different types in array, it may not be a one step process. Here is an idea for you:

```
var json = "[2, \"2\", \"text\"]";
var array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json);

foreach (var item in array)
{
    switch (item.Type)
    {
        case JTokenType.Integer:
            // todo: your parsing code
            break;
        case JTokenType.String:
            break;
        // etc.
    }
}
```

I used [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library to parse JSON. You can install it using nuget:

`Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`

---

If you can, I'd recommend you to fix the JSON source to provide you with a valid JSON that can be parsed to an object without use of low-level classes like `JToken`, `JArray`, `JObject` etc.

Comment: Thank you, I should have told it before. I don't choose the message it's sent by a device.